# Swift check uiswitch status on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch, viewdidload, unwrap

I have a problem with uiswitch. I need to know  if uiswitch is on or off when app run first time.
i tried with this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var switch1: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if switch1.on {
        print("Switch is on")            
    } else {
        print("Switch is off")
    }
}
```

but everytime i get this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How i can unwrap uiswitch without get that error?

Comment: Verify the connection of your IBOutlet, it may be broken.

Comment: there is an error in your code. See "print" line in your else case.

Comment: @HammadRaza: That will be a compilation error, not runtime. OP must have pasted wrong here

Comment: There no problem with your code. Check if outlet is set to your switch in IB. by default  all the UI Controls are unwarpped. Check connectinon in interface builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your switch1 is not connected to the UISwitch in your storyboard or xib.

```
if let switch = switch1 {
  if switch.on {
     print("switch is on")
  } else {
     print("switch is off")
  }
} else {
   println("Where's the switch")   
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem let switch = switch1, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You must call super. All IBOutlets are implicitly unwrapped optional. The are `nil` until `awakeFronNib` is called. If you try to access one of them before that you get an exception.
Also verify that the outlet to the switch is connected.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
     if switch1.on {
        print("Switch is on")
    }
    else {
         print("Switch is off"
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check switch ON/OFF**

```
if switchTapped.isOn == true {
        switchTapped.isOn = true
    }else {
        switchTapped.isOn = false
    }
```